# quickbooks online API, bill with parent resale number doesn't have value

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Referring to the following post:  http://ippdocs.intuit.com/0025_QuickBooksAPI/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Customer/Custom_Fields_for_Customer_and_Job

I am specifically looking for accounts in my QBO that have a parent -> child relationship.  Howewver, in cases where Bill With Parent is true, there is no value coming in for "Resale Number," which I would assume would be the parent's QBO Id?

Any help clarifying on how to pull this information would be helpful.

In C# I'm doing the following and looping the accounts available:

```
    var qboCustomer = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer();
    var qboCustomers = commonService.FindAll(qboCustomer, page, custKnt).ToList();
    custKnt = qboCustomers.Count;
    foreach (var c in qboCustomers)
    {
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BooleanTypeCustomField parentBilling = (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BooleanTypeCustomField)c.CustomField.Where(a => a.DefinitionId == "Bill With Parent").FirstOrDefault();
        if (parentBilling != null)
        {
            if (parentBilling.Value == true)
            {
                Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.StringTypeCustomField resaleNum = (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.StringTypeCustomField)c.CustomField.Where(a => a.DefinitionId == "Resale Number").FirstOrDefault();
                if (resaleNum != null)
                {
                    //do some stuff, however, resaleNum is ALWAYS null...
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cases where Bill With Parent is true is like creating jobs(sub customers) for customers.
The "Resale Number" should be set in the custom fields or on the UI under tax info as shown. 
Then only it is displayed and will not be null. It is not set to the parent's QBO Id.
You code is correct. I verified it. Just set the resaleNum to retrieve it.[image: Job info page]

[image: Get root customer QBOID for a job/sub customer]

Comment: Okay, maybe thats not what I need then.. What I actually need is in your example, the QBOId of the happy entity... is there away to pull that through the API?  It would be acceptable for me to even parse it from the display name i.e. HAPPY : SMILEY FARMS but the API doesn't seem to be returning this anywhere...

Comment: Creating sub customers is like creating jobs in QBO. You need to do a FindById/FindAll on JOB entity and then check the value of the CustomerID and CustomerName in the resultset. I will paste the code soon. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/job

Comment: Edited my answer above to add the code. If you don't the JOBID for your sub customer then do a FindAll and loop through all elements for the CustomerId field.

Comment: Excellent!  Just a note -- the Job id to search for is actually the the Quickbooks Id of the company that has the BillWithParent == true... then the parent of that job is the CustomerId value from the returned job object....  thanks so much for your help, that was the most complete answer I've ever received from stack :)